# getIntent() called in onCreated() block of MyService.java doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters, oncreate

Intent intent is called in onStartCommand which has Intent parameter. But why the intent isn't called in onCreate which has not Intent parameter. Would you please let me know how to call the intent in onCreate which has not Intent
parameter.

1. MainActivity.java
   public void onButtonClicked(View v) {

   ```
   Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

   startService(it);
   }
   ```
2. MyService.java
   public class MyService extends Service {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

   Activity ac = new Activity();
   Intent intent = ac.getIntent();

   if(intent != null) {
       Log.d("MyService", "intent exists");
   } else {
       Log.d("MyService", "intent doesn't exist");
   }

   super.onCreate();
   }
   ```

===> 'intent doesn't exist' in log.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(intent != null) {
        Log.d("MyService", "intent exists");
    } else {
        Log.d("MyService", "intent doesn't exist");
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

===> 'intent exists' in log.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this in your manifest.xml file,

```
<service android:name=".Your_Service_NAme" />
```